# Первый раз работаю с ассемблером и выводит: divide error - overflow. to manually process this error, change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector tab

Tags: ассемблер

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
a DW 2
b DW 3
c DW 4
result DW ?

.code
main PROC
    mov ax, a
    add ax, b     
    mov bx, c     
    imul bx       
    mov dx, 4     
    idiv dx       
    sub ax, dx    
    mov result, ax 

    mov ax, 4C00h 
    int 21h       
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Результат деления не влазит в регистр ax. Прочитайте любую доку по div/idiv. У вас 16-битный операнд, а значит делимое - [dx ax]